# Relative paths in .vimrc

Tags: vim, vimrc

I'd like to add something like

```
let coffee_compiler = '~/repos/coffee-script/bin/coffee'
```

to my `.vimrc`, but vim won't expand the `~` (obviously since it's not my shell).

How can I make this work without including my username? (I am sharing the vimrc file across multiple hosts, so hard-coding the username is a no-no.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this:

The built-in `expand()` function handles special characters and wildcards like the shell:

```
let coffee_compiler = expand('~/repos/coffee-script/bin/coffee')
```

Or, since `~` corresponds to the `HOME` environment variable, you can concatenate its value:

```
let coffee_compiler = $HOME . '/repos/coffee-script/bin/coffee'
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [`$HOME`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_vimrc_file) for this:

```
let coffee_compiler = "$HOME/repos/coffee-script/bin/coffee"
```